# Special bitwise operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I want to perform an bitwise operation on a set of numbers. 
Let's assume the numbers 11, 18, 2 and 8. The operation is as follows:

```
01011
10010
00010
01000

01010 (ans)
```

Logic when n is even - For a set of n numbers the ith bit of result is 0 if at least n/2 +1 of the numbers have ith bit set to zero.
The ith bit of result is 1 if at least n/2 of the numbers have ith bit set to one

Logic when n is odd - For a set of n numbers the ith bit of result is 0 if at least (n+1)/2 of the numbers have ith bit set to zero.
The ith bit of result is 1 if at least (n+1)/2 of the numbers have ith bit set to one

In a nutshell: If there are more zero bits than one bits then the result for that position will be zero else the result will be one

What can be the fastest way to compute this?

Operation should be associative. 
The numbers are 32 bit long and there can be as many 100000 numbers.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you always dealing with a set of exactly 4 numbers? If not, how exactly does your bit-setting-logic work? And how big can the numbers in your set become (important if you're dealing with bits - there might be huge time savings if they fit into registers)?

Comment: @Pascal check edit

Comment: What happens when you have 01, 10 and 00 in your set? How does the result look then?

Comment: The ans is 00. I made the logic more generic in the question

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do this with a loop that runs 32 times, once for each bit in the number.

The you mask out all the bits except the ones you want, add the masked numbers and look at the result - it gives you the number of 1 bits.

E.g. something like this:

```
numbers = [ ..... ]
for i in range(32):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        s + = (numbers[i] & 1)
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] >> 2
    if s < n / 2:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

I haven't tested it, but you can see where it's going.

Another idea that might be faster is to only loop through your numbers once and keep count of who is winning - 0's or 1's for all 32 bits in parallel. You can use four byte-lookup tables for this, and keep 32 counters in an array that get updated by the looked-up values.

Comment: thanks! I did something like this, and it wasnt slow. I was looking for O(1) solution. But looks like this is good enough. Thanks

Comment: O(1) is impossible since your input size is n (the number of numbers in your set), so you can't get better than O(n). But in your case, n is probably very small, so it just doesn't matter much.